# Unable to send email to yahoo email using PHP

Tags: php, email, xampp, yahoo

My script worked as it displayed 'Message sent!' but no email was received to the indicated email. Using XAMPP btw. Appreciate the help. Thank you.

```
<?php
$to = 'theaccount@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'Sample Subject';
$message = 'Hi. This is a sample message.';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@august.ai.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: no-reply@august.ai.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

echo (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) ? 'Message sent!' : 'Message not sent!';
?>
```

Here is the info from my **php.ini** and **sendmail.ini**:

**php.ini**:

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
; SMTP = theaccount@yahoo.com
; smtp_port = 25
```

**sendmail.ini**:

```
smtp_server=smtp.mail.yahoo.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25

auth_username=theaccount+yahoo.com      
auth_password=passwordhere
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't "commented out" the `php.ini`'s SMTP configuration lines:

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
; SMTP = theaccount@yahoo.com
; smtp_port = 25
```

For `php.ini` file, semicolons `;` are used for comments. So you need to remove it from those lines:

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
SMTP = theaccount@yahoo.com
smtp_port = 25
```

Try that out :)

Comment: Mmmhh cr@ap :/ I never really needed to send mails locally, so I don't know exactly what to do. I think the way is to try to debug deeper. It may be hard to do that using php's native `mail()` function as it doesn't output any errors, so I would recommend you using some lib such as [PhpMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) for that. Also, it's a great tool for further use!

Comment: will try PhpMailer. Thanks!!